# Strange lines on turtle plastron

Tags: reptiles, turtles

My four year old yellow bellied slider has some strange lines in his plastron. I couldn't tell how long have those been there, I think for a long time, maybe even years, but it's something that's starting to worry me a bit.

The plastron itself feels hard and firm, carefully pressing it doesn't give in at all, even with a moderate pressure.

Other than this he looks (and behaves) healthily.

[image: Lines in turtle plastron]

You can see the straight lines that cross the lower scutes from side to side. They are clearer yellow than the rest of the plastron, with a pinkish halo around them.

[image: color corrected version]

I've emphasised the colours in this picture to make the lines more apparent.

Comment: Could it be a mark from the favorite position on the basking area?

Comment: @Allerleirauh That's a good suggestion, but because of their placement at the time, there where some moving shadows that forced them to change positions every now and then to chase the sunlight.